# QuickFIX Invalid message: Expected BodyLength=454, Recieved BodyLength=469

Tags: quickfix

When receiving a ExecutionReport (35=n) i receive the below error

QuickMessage: Invalid message: Expected BodyLength=454, Recieved BodyLength=469

Sample Vendor Message

8=FIX.4.29=46935=n34=13208369=1952=20150324-08:07:58.91943=Y49=CME50=7056=UAT12357=P122=20150324-07:57:04.201212=350213=8=FIX.4.29=31435=834=15294369=775852=20150324-07:57:04.19949=CME50=7056=AZT000N57=DUMMY143=US,IL1=003316=011=ACP142718382415514=017=70477:206612220=037=7029490619138=1039=040=241=044=50448=806054=155=HW59=060=20150324-07:57:04.198107=HWJ5150=0151=10167=FUT432=201503241028=Y9717=ACP142718382415510=03910=097

Comment: Use http://www.fixtradingcommunity.org/FIXimate/FIXimate3.0/latestEP/ and find out if you are missing any fields. And check if you are receiving the full message. This is basic checks which you should have done, but doesn't seem so.

Comment: You should insert visible field separators into the message that you pasted.  Without them, it's hard to read all the fields.

Comment: 8=FIX.4.2|9=542|35=n|34=26718|369=114|52=20150325-10:08:13.330|49=CME|50=50|56=30CMSGN|57=P|212=453|213=<RTRF>8=FIX.4.2|9=417|35=8|34=30072|369=13704|52=20150325-10:08:13.329|49=CME|50=50|56=AZT000N|57=DUMMY|143=US,IL|1=00331|6=0|11=ACP1427278093281|14=9|17=50480:M:18437TN0001414|20=0|31=5.5|32=9|37=50100583755|38=9|39=2|40=2|41=0|44=5.5|48=806656|54=2|55=ZE|59=0|60=20150325-10:08:13.328|75=20150325|107=GEZ7 C9975|150=2|151=0|167=OPT|337=TRADE|375=CME000A|432=20150325|442=1|527=50100583755201503251414|1028=Y|1057=Y|9717=ACP1427278093282|10=171|</RTRF>|10=252